# Как создать классы по существующей БД в intellij IDEA

Tags: mysql, база-данных, intellij-idea

Eсть БД с SQL скриптами по созданию таблиц. Есть Intellij IDEA, в проект которой подлючена данная БД. Проект пока что пустой. ***Как в Intellij IDEA по БД создать класы, описывающие таблицы из БД?*** Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Средствами IDE автоматически это реализовать невозможно - редактор не может знать, какой стандарт кодирования вы используете, работаете ли с пространствами имён, используете ли какой-то базовый класс и т.п. Но если вы используете какой-то фреймворк, то там могут быть пакеты для этого.

Comment: @АлексейУколов Странно, а в NetBeans такая функция возможна